# How to change the color of 1 sentence in the <p> </ p> tag without adding a new line?

Tags: html

I have a closed text in the `<p></p>` tags. I would like to change the color of one sentence to red. Unfortunately, using another `<p></p>` results in a line break.

I would like to get this effect:
[image]

Comment: There is a `span` tag for this.

Answer (score 1):

This should help, use span instead of new p:

EXAMPLE

```
<p>My mother has <span style="color:blue">blue</span> eyes.</p>
```

Then add your style inside the span like the example :)

Answer (score -1):

you could use the following code using font instead f a second p

```
<p>this is<font color=red>a</font>
```

the color can be set to your preference

Comment: The `<font>` element was deprecated from HTML over 20 years ago.